# How to use unittest.TestSuite in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-unittest

In the future, I'll need to add many identical tests with different parameters. Now I am making a sample test suite:

```
import unittest

class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, methodName='runTest', param=None):
        super(TestCase, self).__init__(methodName)
        self.param = param

    def test_something(self):
        print '\n>>>>>> test_something: param =', self.param
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    testloader = unittest.TestLoader()
    testnames = testloader.getTestCaseNames(TestCase)
    for name in testnames:
        suite.addTest(TestCase(name, param=42))
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

It gets discovered by VS Code:

```
start
test.test_navigator.TestCase.test_something
```

When I run the tests, I don't receive the parameter:

```
test_something (test.test_navigator.TestCase) ... 
>>>>>> test_something: param = None
ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

If I run this file directly, everything works as expected (note `param = 42` part)

```
test_something (__main__.TestCase) ...
>>>>>> test_something: param = 42
ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

So it looks like VS Code is running the tests on its own just by using the discovered classes and ignoring TestSuite completely?

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to implement the `load_tests` function:

```
def load_tests(loader, tests, pattern):
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    testnames = loader.getTestCaseNames(TestCase)
    for name in testnames:
        suite.addTest(TestCase(name, param=42))
        suite.addTest(TestCase(name, param=84))
    return suite
```

The documentation says:

> If load_tests exists then discovery does not recurse into the package, load_tests is responsible for loading all tests in the package.

Now my tests run as expected.

P.S. Thanks to Brett Cannon for pointing me to Unit testing framework documentation

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your code is in a `if __name__ == "__main__"` block which is only executed when you point Python directly at the file. So when the extension asks `unittest` to get all the tests and then run them for us it doesn't run the code in your `if __name__ == "__main__"` block (which is why it can find it but it doesn't do anything magical).

If you can get it to work using [`unittest`'s command-line interface](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface) then the extension should run it as you want it to.

Comment: If I remove the `if __name__ == "__main__"` condition then the tests are executed two times: one time in a suite as expected and one time as individual tests. Also they are executed on discovery.

Comment: So while playing with unittest's CLI I realized that it's not a VS Code problem but the unittest's itself. I am getting the same behavior from CLI. I can't get the tests executed in a suite without getting them executed as standalone.